# Configuring uploading images in JCE

Tags: image, joomla, joomla-content-editor

Within JCE, how can I limit the images displayed in a gallery and save the uploaded image in specific director (say, `YEAR/DAY/`) so that images would organized by date?

Answer (score 0):

Add the [$id](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/documentation/100-profiles/319-profiles-plugin-parameters) or similar that is unique to the user to the upload folder/path in the settings.

Comment: thanks for response. I want to buy a pc with 240 ssd, devide into 2 volumes, 40gb for windows, and 200gb for d volume with only d:\wamp64\www\ folder for better mysql and many small php file work faster in SSD. Because of capacity of SSD is small i will add another 320gb hdd, and i'll make it volume F:. is it possible to save image files uploaded through JCE editor save in volume F: for example in folder F:\sitefolder\images, because i am making conjucture that images uploaded will take main disk space.